# Android Data Policy

Tags: android

Android Data Policy
I Couldn't Get Over This Policy
However, I Do Not Share Anything, There Is No Information Registered
Is There An Example About This?
If I Can't Pass, My Application Will Not Be Published

solved

I Solved the Problem Solution is as follows: Google Play Console->App content in Completions I Shared a .doc with Data Policy Added to the Privacy Policy via Google Drive Warning in the Items to be Completed Tab I Updated the Declaration Say Declaration (Data Security) The Screen That Appears Next Does the Application Collect or Share Any of the Mandatory User Types: Yes Is All User Data Collected by Your Application Encrypted During Transfer: Yes Do You Provide a Method for Users to Request Deletion of Their Data: No
Forward Location: Exact Location Ciyaz or Other Identities: Ciyaz or Other Identities Marked forward Click on the Arrow to the Right of the Exact Location (Start) Collected Marked Next Article Marked Yes Data is Mandatory Collected..... Checked Analysis Marked Developer Communications Marked Save Collected is ticked on the next screen. Checked Yes in the Next Item Data is Mandatory Collected..... Checked Developer Communications Marked Save Forward I Finished the Process with Save and Then Review Procedures
Note: I use Firebase, Analytics and Crashlytics in my application. I realized that I received a data policy warning for these three.

Comment: Please read carefully on the console. Share here a screenshot

Comment: Since I use Turkish, I had to use Google Language Translation. I sent it this way instead of a screenshot.

Data Security section in Google Play User Data Policy: Data Security Form is invalid
details
We reviewed your app's Data Security Form section in the Play Console and found inconsistencies between this section and how the app collects and shares user data. All applications must accurately disclose their data collection and sharing methods in the Data Security Form section. This obligation also applies to applications that do not collect user data.

Comment: It has been determined that user data is transferred outside the device, but it is not declared that this data is collected in your application's Data Security Form.

Comment: You need to ensure that your app's Data Security section accurately reflects the ways your app collects, shares, and processes data. This includes data collected and processed through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in your app. Where appropriate, we've added details about SDKs that contain code similar to the code in your APK and may be sending user data on the device. You can check if your app uses any of these SDKs. However, note that this SDK list may not be exhaustive. You must review and disclose all data collected and shared by your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely your app sends data to some server on the internet. It is not your fault, but your app uses some library that it does. You can declare that your app manage data

Comment: I Solved the Problem
Solution is as follows:
Google Play Console->App content in Completions
I Shared a .doc with Data Policy Added to the Privacy Policy via Google Drive
Warning in the Items to be Completed Tab
I Updated the Declaration
Say Declaration (Data Security)
The Screen That Appears Next
Does the Application Collect or Share Any of the Mandatory User Types: Yes
Is All User Data Collected by Your Application Encrypted During Transfer: Yes
Do You Provide a Method for Users to Request Deletion of Their Data: No

Comment: Forward
Location: Exact Location
Ciyaz or Other Identities: Ciyaz or Other Identities Marked
forward
Click on the Arrow to the Right of the Exact Location (Start)
Collected Marked
Next Article Marked Yes
Data is Mandatory Collected..... Checked
Analysis Marked
Developer Communications Marked
Save
Collected is ticked on the next screen.
Checked Yes in the Next Item
Data is Mandatory Collected..... Checked
Developer Communications Marked
Save
Forward
I Finished the Process with Save and Then Review Procedures

Comment: Note: I use Firebase, Analytics and Crashlytics in my application. I realized that I received a data policy warning for these three.

Comment: ok, job done. If my answer is right then feel free to mark it as Accepted or Useful